# Repeating secondary headers for grouped data in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

How can I create a kendo grid of following design. Basically, I need to bind grouped data in a kendo grid. For example, same issue can be there with multiple devices, so issue details should be bound once for all the devices with same issue & Make model headers should repeat for each issue

[image]

How can I make Make, Model headers to repeat for each issue group

I could create following:

[image]

with below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html>  
    <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title>Reorder Column</title>  
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.common.min.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.default.min.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">  
    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/angular.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/jszip.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>  
    <body>  
    <div id="example">  
        <div id="grid"></div>  
        <script>  
            $(document).ready(function() {  
            
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({  
                columns: [  
                    { field: "Issue", title:"Issue"},
                    { field: "Description", title:"Description"},
                    { field:"Components", columns:[                  
                        { field: "Make", title: "Make"},
                        { field: "Model", title: "Model"}, 
                    ]}
                ],  
                dataSource: [  
                { Issue: "1", Description: "Test", Make: "K1", Model: "L1"},  
                { Issue: "1", Description: "Test", Make: "K2", Model: "L2"},
                { Issue: "1", Description: "Test", Make: "K3", Model: "L3"},
                { Issue: "2", Description: "Check", Make: "K4", Model: "L4"},
                { Issue: "2", Description: "Check", Make: "K4", Model: "L4"}] ,
            reorderable: true
                }); 
                // Merging cells should start from Right to Left. Otherwise, column index will change & hence will create issue 
                mergeGridRows("grid", "Description"); 
                mergeGridRows("grid", "Issue"); 

            });  
            function mergeGridRows(gridId, colTitle) {
                // looping through grid data
                $('#' + gridId + '>.k-grid-content>table').each(function (index, item) {
                    var colIndex = 1;
                    // looping through grid header
                    $('#' + gridId + '>.k-grid-header>.k-grid-header-wrap>table').find('th').each(function () {
                        // Get the column for which rows need to be merged
                        if ($(this).text() == colTitle) {
                            // first instance of the identical cell(td) value to be merged
                            var firstCell = null;
                            $(item).find('tr').each(function () {
                                // get the td to be merged
                                var currentCell = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + colIndex + ')');
                                if (firstCell == null) {
                                    firstCell = currentCell;
                                } else if (currentCell.text() == firstCell.text()) {
                                    // if value in current td & prevous td is same, remove the current td & increase rowspan of the 1st td
                                    currentCell.remove();
                                    var firstCellRowSpan = firstCell.attr('rowspan');
                                    // increment rowspan of the first td
                                    firstCell.attr('rowspan', typeof firstCellRowSpan == "undefined" ? 2 : parseInt(firstCellRowSpan) + 1);
                                } 
                                else {
                                    // this cell is different from the last
                                    firstCell = currentCell;
                                }
                            });
                            return;
                        }
                        // increment the col index, to scan for the next td, nth column may need merging
                        colIndex++;
                    });
                });
            }
            </script>  
        </div>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JS function to inject a new row after each group of data. It's not very generic, but solved my purpose. Below is the code snippet

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>  
                <html>  
                <head>  
                <meta charset="utf-8">  
                <title>Reorder Column</title>  
                
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.common.min.css">  
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">  
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.default.min.css">  
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">  
                
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>  
                <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/angular.min.js"></script>  
                <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/jszip.min.js"></script>  
                <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>  
                <body>  
                <div id="example">  
                    <div id="grid"></div>  
                    <script>  
                        $(document).ready(function() {  
                        
                            $("#grid").kendoGrid({  
                            columns: [  
                                { field: "Issue", title:"Issue"},
                                { field: "Description", title:"Description"},
                                { field:"Components", columns:[                  
                                    { field: "Make", title: "Make"},
                                    { field: "Model", title: "Model"}, 
                                ]}
                            ],  
                            dataSource: [  
                            { Issue: "1", Description: "Test", Make: "K1", Model: "L1"},  
                            { Issue: "1", Description: "Test", Make: "K2", Model: "L2"},
                            { Issue: "1", Description: "Test", Make: "K3", Model: "L3"},
                            { Issue: "2", Description: "Check", Make: "K4", Model: "L4"},
                            { Issue: "2", Description: "Check", Make: "K4", Model: "L4"}] ,
                        reorderable: true
                            }); 
                            addGroupHeader("grid", "Description");

                            // Merging cells should start from Right to Left. Otherwise, column index will change & hence will create issue 
                            mergeGridRows("grid", "Description"); 
                            mergeGridRows("grid", "Issue"); 

                        });  
                        function mergeGridRows(gridId, colTitle) {
                            // looping through grid data
                            $('#' + gridId + '>.k-grid-content>table').each(function (index, item) {
                                var colIndex = 1;
                                // looping through grid header
                                $('#' + gridId + '>.k-grid-header>.k-grid-header-wrap>table').find('th').each(function () {
                                    // Get the column for which rows need to be merged
                                    if ($(this).text() == colTitle) {
                                        // first instance of the identical cell(td) value to be merged
                                        var firstCell = null;
                                        $(item).find('tr').each(function () {
                                            // get the td to be merged
                                            var currentCell = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + colIndex + ')');
                                            if (firstCell == null) {  
                                                firstCell = currentCell;
                                            } else if (currentCell.text() == firstCell.text()) {
                                                // if value in current td & prevous td is same, remove the current td & increase rowspan of the 1st td
                                                currentCell.remove();
                                                var firstCellRowSpan = firstCell.attr('rowspan');
                                                // increment rowspan of the first td
                                                firstCell.attr('rowspan', typeof firstCellRowSpan == "undefined" ? 2 : parseInt(firstCellRowSpan) + 1);
                                            } 
                                            else {
                                                // this cell is different from the last
                                                firstCell = currentCell;
                                            }
                                        });
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    // increment the col index, to scan for the next td, nth column may need merging
                                    colIndex++;
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        // title of column, after which secondary header should be placed
                        function addGroupHeader(gridId, colTitle){
                            // When value in 2 adjacent cells for the column varies, add a tr with secondary header
                            // looping through grid data
                            $('#' + gridId + '>.k-grid-content>table').each(function (index, item) {
                                var colIndex = 1;
                                // looping through grid header
                                $('#' + gridId + '>.k-grid-header>.k-grid-header-wrap>table').find('th').each(function () {
                                    // Get the column for which rows need to be merged
                                    if ($(this).text() == colTitle) {
                                        // first instance of the identical cell(td) value to be merged
                                        var firstCell = null;
                                        $(item).find('tr').each(function () {
                                            // get the td to be merged
                                            var currentCell = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + colIndex + ')');
                                            if (firstCell == null) {  
                                                firstCell = currentCell;
                                            } else if (currentCell.text() !== firstCell.text()) {
                                                // if value in current td & prevous td are different, add a tr before parent of first cell
                                                $('<tr><td></td><td></td><td class = "secondaryheader">Make</td><td class = "secondaryheader">Model</td></tr>').insertAfter(firstCell.parent());
                                            } 
                                            firstCell = currentCell;
                                        });
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    // increment the col index, to scan for the next td, nth column may need grouping
                                    colIndex++;
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        </script> 
                        <style>
                            .secondaryheader{
                                font-weight: bold;
                                border: 1px solid black !important;
                            }
                        </style> 
                    </div>  
                
                </body>  
                </html>
```